# sed - regexp - adding rounded parenthesis on a mathematical expression

Tags: regex, bash, math, sed

I'm trying to write a sed command with a regex with the purpose to add rounded parenthesis around numbers to be added.

In particular, considering this expression example `86 * 21 + 7 * 13 * 31 + 26 + 31 * 5` I would like to have a result as `86 * (21 + 7) * 13 * (31 + 26 + 31) * 5`.

I created the following sed command: `sed -e 's/\([0-9]\+ +.[0-9]\+\)/(\1)/g' expr.txt` but I'm able only to set rounder parenthesis each 2 numbers and not more, like `86 * (21 + 7) * 13 * (31 + 26) + 31 * 5`.

I also tried to use `sed -e 's/\([0-9]\+ +.*[^\*].*[0-9]\+[^ \*]\)/(\1)/g'` (specifically `[^*] in order to exclude the multiplication) with no luck.

How can I reach to have a result that is able to set rounded parenthesis for all concatenated addition operations like `86 * (21 + 7) * 13 * (31 + 26 + 31) * 5`?

How to manage particular cases like:

- `23 + (2 * 53) + (34 * 66) * 55` that should produce `((23 + (2 * 53)) + (34 * 66)) * 55`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\+\( + [0-9]\+\)\+\)/(\1)/g'
```

Personally, I prefer the `-E` style where `()` and `+` are operators by default and have to be escaped to denote literals:

```
sed -E 's/([0-9]+( \+ [0-9]+)+)/(\1)/g'
```

Comment: Yes, it works as expected. The only doubt I see is when we have an expression that already have parenthesis, for example `(5 + 37) + (10 + 1) * 25 * 57 + 5 + 61 + 74 + 56 + 5 * 74`. The result will be `((5 + 37)) + ((10 + 1)) * 25 * 57 + 5 + 61 + 74 + 56 + 5 * 74`, and maybe it should be correct to have `((5 + 37) + (10 + 1)) * 25 * 57 + 5 + 61 + 74 + 56 + 5 * 74`.

Comment: If you want to process inputs that already contain parentheses, I'd strongly advise you to switch from regexes to something more powerful. Plain old regexes are not powerful enough to handle context-free grammars like mathematical expressions with parentheses.